# Update row in sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to update a row in a table in sqlite in android but it update all rows and not just the row that I want.

This is my code:

```
public void EditarLinhaRecorrencia(int escolhaMensal
   , int escolhaSemanal
   , int escolhaDiaria
   , int escolhaOutro
   , int frequencia
   , String hora
   , String iDPrescricao)
{
    ContentValues valores =new ContentValues();
    valores.put("Mensal", escolhaMensal);
    valores.put("Semanal", escolhaSemanal);
    valores.put("Diario", escolhaDiaria);
    valores.put("OutrasFrequencias",escolhaOutro);
    valores.put("Frequencia",frequencia);
    valores.put("HoraTomas",hora);
    abrir();
    this.db.update("Recorrencia",valores, iDPrescricao,null);
    fechar();
}
```

Comment: We dont all know Spanish. Care to post what iDPrescricao is?

Comment: it's portuguese or galician. Or some sort of west iberian language. it means prescription.

Comment: Yeah but we need to know it's value :P

Comment: well it's the where clause. like `WHERE prescription =` and there are no 'where' arguments. which is probably his problem... he needs arguments to the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

counting that the prescription column is named 'prescricao'

```
String whereComparison = "prescricao=" + iDPrescricao;
...
this.db.update("Recorrencia", valores, whereComparison, null);
```